# How do I remove a site from IIS7 using JavaScript?

Tags: iis-7, javascript

I've been searching the Internet for a way to remove a site from IIS7 using JavaScript. I've found, and used, a lot of examples on how to create a site and applications using JavaScript but not a single example on how to delete a site!

For example, I've figured out how to create a site using the examples found at http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites.

Does anyone know how to remove a site from IIS7 using JavaScript?

Please help!

/Petteri

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not meant to perform server side infrastructure operations - but if you insist on doing it you should wrap your operation (deleting the site using C#) in a web service exposed to JavaScript via static Page methods (assuming you are using asp.net) and throw in a ScriptManager to access your web service. That way you can access the functionality to remove the site via JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, if you follow the link in the question you'll see that Windows Server accepts JavaScript as scripting language.